# Allow Animation in SVG Object to Begin onScroll

Tags: jquery, svg, css-animations

I have a circle graph that I am trying to test animations on. I am having issues with the chart appearing onScroll. I have been able to add the entire object load onScroll, but then the animation begins prior to the overall object loading. Is there a way I can only start the orange bar once a users scrolls to the object?

CSS

```
.single-chart {
  width: 33%;
  justify-content: space-around ;
}
.circular-chart {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 250px;
}
.circle-bg {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #eee;
  stroke-width: 3.8;
}
.circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2.8;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  animation: progress 1s ease-out forwards;
}
.circular-chart.onScroll {
  animation: progress .9s;
}
@keyframes progress {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
  }
}
.circular-chart.orange .circle {
  stroke: #ff9f00;
}
.percentage {
  fill: #666;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  text-anchor: middle;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="single-chart" style="padding-top:500px;">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart orange">
      <path class="circle-bg"
        d="M18 2.0845
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
      />
      <path class="circle"
        stroke-dasharray="30, 100"
        d="M18 2.0845
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
      />
      <text x="18" y="20.35" class="percentage">30%</text>
    </svg>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
<script>
var scrollpos = window.scrollY; // window scroll position
var wh = window.innerHeight-50; // as soon as element touches bottom with offset event starts
var element = document.querySelector(".circular-chart"); //element

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){ 
    if(scrollpos > (element.offsetTop - wh)){
        element.classList.add("onScroll");
    }
});</script>
```

Comment: SVG doesn't have offsetTop, so I used `element.getBoundingClientRect();` to get the bottom position of the element relative to the top left of the viewport - and check if that's smaller than the window's current height (note I also added the class to `.circle` instead of `.circular-chart`, and modified the CSS to reflect this): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WLgGaL

Comment: Oh got it! Thank you so much for the help on this @mark.hch !

Comment: This method will only work for animating the first instance of     .circle, right?

Comment: Technically, just because you're using `querySelector`, which only selects the first element the selector matches. If you assign them to separate variables, there's no reason you can't work on multiple instances of the circle. I updated the same pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WLgGaL

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! In your opinion, do you think this is efficient, or would you prefer to use a different method?

Comment: I see no problem with this method. As with anything programming related there are many ways to achieve the same end result, but as long as it works and isn't causing any issues, I see no reason to change how you're doing it.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, @mark.hch this has been very helpful for me!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of addeventlisgener make it onScroll. Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onscroll

And do not try to do everything with jquery, JavaScript is also a language but it is yet to come you are learning.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I will try out your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to animate is the `stroke-dashoffset` from 100 to 100 - 30. I hope it helps.

```js
let sc = document.querySelector(".single-chart");
var element = document.querySelector(".circular-chart"); 

var scrollpos = window.scrollY; // window scroll position
var wh = window.innerHeight-50; // as soon as element touches bottom with offset event starts
//element

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){ 
  let bcr = sc.getBoundingClientRect();
    if(bcr.y < wh){
        element.classList.add("onScroll");
    }
});
```

```css
.single-chart {
  width: 33%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  
  border:5px solid red
}
.circular-chart {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 250px;
}
.circle-bg {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #eee;
  stroke-width: 3.8;
}
.circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2.8;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 100;
  stroke-dashoffset:100;
  /*animation: progress 1s ease-out forwards;*/
}
.circular-chart.onScroll .circle { 
  animation: progress 4s ease-out forwards;
}
@keyframes progress {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 70;
  }
}
.circular-chart.orange .circle {
  stroke: #ff9f00;
}
.percentage {
  fill: #666;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  text-anchor: middle;
}
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<div class="single-chart" style="margin-top:700px;">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart orange">
      <path class="circle-bg"
        d="M18 2.0845
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
      />
      <path class="circle"
        d="M18 2.0845
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
          a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
      />
      <text x="18" y="20.35" class="percentage">30%</text>
    </svg>
</div>
```